# FluentValidation testing with RuleSets

Tags: fluentvalidation

Im writing some test for a FluentValidator that contains RuleSets like this:

```
        RuleSet("Patch", () =>
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty();
        });
```

and I test this with `FluentValidation.TestHelper`, the test look like this:

```
 _sut.ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor(x => x.Name, string.Empty);
```

The problem is that the `ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor` dont go in the `RuleSet` therefore the `NotEmpty` check dont fires.

How do I specify the test to use the the `RuleSet` "Patch"?

Thanks!

Comment: I will awnser my own question, the ShouldHaveValidationErrorFor takes RuleSet as a third parameter.... Im stupid bye